# Make a simple HTML form checker that redirects if password correct?

Tags: html, passwords, plaintext

I'm not looking for anything that's secure, the password will be plaintext in the html document, this is purely for me testing. What I want to know is how can i include a statement that checks if the password is correct in the following code, and redirects to a 'win.html' if it does.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form action="">
  <input name="username" id="username" type="text">
  <input name="pass" id="pass" type="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I haven't done web development in awhile but this is how i would try to do what you're attempting if you don't care about the security

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form>
<input name="username" id="username" type="text">
<input name="pass" id="pass" type="password">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
</form> 


<script>
function myFunction(){
  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

if(user == "Admin" && pass == "Password"){
            window.location.href="win.html"
        alert("correct");
   }else{
    alert("Incorrect username or password");
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Username is Admin
Passowrd is Password

**Changed the button type from submit to Button as i believe it was stopping the redirect**

Comment: It looks like it would work, but when inputting the correct or incorrect details it doesn't do anything. Thanks though

Comment: Hey Jim i changed my code it should work now if you just copy and paste it.

I believe having the button type as "submit" was stopping the redirect of the webpage but this also means pressing enter wont submit the form. Also this may not be the best way but it should work ^-^

Comment: Close, but no cigar. it redirects me to mydomain.com/myfunction()?username=Admin&pass=Password

Comment: Did you copy the code exsactly? And what Browser are you using

Comment: Also do you have win.html in the same folder as your original html document

Comment: You're missing a semicolon from the redirect line. Also, you cannot do alert() after redirecting.

Comment: I was meant to remove the alert it was originally there to test the if statement and forgot to take it out when inserting the window.location =\

Comment: You can fix it by clicking the grey "edit" button under your answer.